Problem about showing a space is Hausdorff
Given two topological spaces $X$, $Y$. $Y$ is Hausdorff and a continuous surjection $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ such that each $f^{-1}\{y\}$ is Hausdorff. I am asked to show $X$ is Hausdorff as well. I've tried the following :
For any two points $x_1\neq x_2,$ in $X$.
Case 1: If $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ it is easy. You just use the Hausdorffness of $Y$ to find two disjoint open nbhds of $f(x_1),f(x_2)$ resp. and pull them back to $X.$
Case 2: If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y.$  Since $f^{-1}\{y\}$ is Hausdorff and using the definition of the subspace topology we have two nbhds $U_1, U_2$ of $x_1,x_2$ resp. s.t. $U_1\cap f^{-1}\{y\}\cap U_2 \cap f^{-1}\{y\}= \emptyset .$ i.e. $U_1\cap U_2 \cap f^{-1}\{y\}.$ I think $U_1$ and $U_2$ are our desired nbhds (Maybe the only choice because I did not see any other option) and I had some problems with showing their intersection is empty. I tried to use the property of a surjection $f(f^{-1})(U)=U$ but failed.
Any hints and solutions are appreciated ! Thanks in advance!

This is not true. Indeed, if $X$ is the line with two origins, $Y = \mathbb{R}$, and $f: X \to Y$ maps both origins in $X$ to the origin in $Y$ and every other point to themselves, then $f$ is a continuous surjection, $Y$ is Hausdorff, and $f^{-1}\{y\}$ is Hausdorff for every $y \in Y$. However, $X$ is not Hausdorff.

Thanks, I have been struggling with this for a whole afternoon :-(
